# is there a way to override android api 26+ background activity restrictions?

Tags: java, android

i'm building an app that uses a service that scans for wifi (wifimanager.startscan()) every 2 minutes.
Since android api 26+ when background restrictions were introduced, it is not possible to scan for wifi from a background service.
Is there a way to override these restrictions?
I saw an answer that involved an 9intent like such:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS");
context.registerReceiver(new InOutWifiScanResultsReceiver(), intentFilter);
```

but this didn't work for a reason I dont know

Comment: Use Foreground service or WorkerManager. Depends on your needs

Comment: thanks works fine not using it in the end i've decided to use ble instead but thanks anyway